# PowerShell ISE running previously ran script on running new script

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

PowerShell ISE
I have two scripts : A.ps1 and B.ps1

1> I will run A.ps1 Script. It Ran successfully and Logging logs in local file.
2> On running B.ps1 script. Still executing A.Ps1 script in ISE and logging A.Ps1 script logs.
Can anyone help on this.

Comment: You’d be better off providing more details and possibly the scripts themselves. As it stands, I do not believe anyone is going to be able to assist you since there isn’t much to go off of.

Comment: This scripts. A.ps1 to stop and start instances. and B.ps1 to register and deregister instance in aws. Both file have separate log files. when i run A.ps1 script it run's perfectly and  logs properly. after when I run B.ps1 script. instead of running script B.ps1 PowerShell ISE running previously ran script i.e. A.ps1 and logging there logs also.

Comment: the ISE **_does not clear anything out unless you do it manually_**. that means that any $Vars you define in a session _remain in that session_ until you exit that session OR manually clear those $Vars.

Comment: What command are you using to log? `Add-AWSLoggingListener`? Please add the relevant parts of your scripts

Comment: using local txt file to log. Add-Content $Logpath(" message ") and I have two methods in script. 1 to check aws module and another to perform tasks as mentioned previously